# Many - Many Relationship Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

I have a condition where I have many-many for my two entities:

> A category can have many places, in other hand, places can be also
>   under many categories

The data are successfully stored in my sqlite, but when I check the structure of both entites in sqlite manager software, the relationship between two of it is gone.

Usually, when I declare 1..* , for example:

> Entity B has one entity A
>
> Place is under one category

Category will become an attribute in Place, where I can use it for later use:

```
Category *category = (Category*)place.category;
NSString *catId = category.catId;
```

and it should returns a value of `catId` if there is value there.

But in my many-many case, I can't even get the `catId`, it crashes like this:

```
-[_NSFaultingMutableSet catID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Do I miss a concept here? I believe core data supports many to many relationship as I've read it in some web. Thanks!

Comment: Post the code for your Category class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 'to-many' relationship from Place->Category, so `place.category` is a `NSMutableSet` object not a `Category` object

Try this

```
NSMutableSet *categorySet = place.category;

foreach (Category *category in categorySet)
{
    NSString *catId = category.catId;
    NSLog(@"catId: %@", catId);
}
```

Comment: I thought it was a bug or missing concept.. but I miss that it becomes a NSMutableSet! Thanks trapper!!!